# Can we generate DTMF tones using python?

Tags: python, telecommunication

i am keen to know whether we can generate a DTMF tones using python? If yes then is there any library to do so? I have checked on the net there i could find sample program to decode the DTMF tones but not vice-versa. It would be great if anyone can give me some hint.
Thanks,
Rupesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use samples of the dtmf tones and play them back from wav files for example. You could use [this website](http://www.dialabc.com/sound/generate/) to create the samples

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. It will be very kind of you if you can give me some hint about how to send those DTMF tones through modem using python?

Comment: @Rupesh Chavan That's a separate question, you should ask it as such.